# box-api is still using v1

Tags: box-api

Any one has idea when will box-api get upgraded it is still using same old v1.

```
there is no implementation for the latest api's
```

does any one using the latest box-api?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what 'box-api' refers to? Is this a module for a specific language somewher?

Comment: There is an unmerged branch in the repository at https://github.com/box/box-ruby-sdk that appears to support v2.0, but no word on whether it's ready for production usage. I too would appreciate some official comment on this.

Comment: write now the api which "box-api" gem implements is of v1 which is little outdated.. the implementations are pretty old

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably check out the attachements.me ruby sdk that they just posted

https://github.com/attachmentsme/ruby-box

Answer (score 0):

That particular gem is maintained by a member of our developer community, and we're not actively maintaining it. Your best option is to work with the developer who is maintaining it to update it for the API.